# Indexing using input matrix RcppArmadillo

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

I have two vectors.. one is an output by group and the second is an index for the appartenance to one group. In practice, it is something like that

mean_group = 1, 2, 3

group_id  = 1,1,3,2,3,2

And I would like to to assign each id to the value of its group.. In basic R, I will just do mean_group[group_id]..

I have to avoid using a loop, otherwise, there would be no point in using armadillo. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how hard you tried to find this in the Armadillo documentation, but this works out of the box in Armadillo. Try the following as file `armaind.cpp`:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec subsetter(arma::vec big, arma::uvec ind) {
  arma::vec small = big.elem( ind );
  return small;
}

/*** R
big <- 2*(1:10)
ind <- c(3,5,7)
subsetter(big, ind)
*/
```

which gets you

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/armaind.cpp")

R> big <- 2*(1:10)

R> ind <- c(3,5,7)

R> subsetter(big, ind)
     [,1]
[1,]    8
[2,]   12
[3,]   16
R>
```

Note the off-by-one indexing difference between R and C++.